# How do i get the the full name of the proxyed type for a nhibernate DynamicProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, castle-windsor, proxy-classes

I am using a netdatacontractserializer and a SerializationBinder to create my own runtime types for nhibernate proxies on the client side.

This all works except I am forced to assume that there is only one type by each name in the domain model. i.e. i am forced to ignore the namespace. The reason is that SerializationBinder only gives me access to "MyObjectProxyb04bae2d04d34e8a98b1d93bf24428cc" and "DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" to derive the parent tyep.

As you can see there is no data that points to the namespace of the parent type.

I have had a look at changing the name of the generated proxy (to include a namespace prefix) but that seems to be hard coded.

Comment: I think some details about why you are trying to change the class name of the proxy object would be useful.

Comment: Please post another question: "How can I find out the proxied type for a DynamicProxy proxy?", this has become quite unrelated to the original question after the edits.

Comment: mausch
good point. I have reworded the question.

Comment: It looks that you'll have to make 2 or 3 *specific* questions out of this one to answer your whole problem... otherwise this question will keep changing and the answers will change too, to the frustration of everyone.

Comment: The proxying question has already been answered, now post another question for the serialization part. Please don't delete or change this question further as it could serve for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the proxy to INHibernateProxy and get the persistent underlying class:

```
((INHibernateProxy)proxy).HibernateLazyInitializer.PersistentClass
```

Comment: how do i do this on the client side after serialization.

Comment: Don't know anything about SerializationBinder, I'm just answering your nhibernate-proxying question.